# Trim data in csv file and remove extra blank header

Tags: php, csv, upload

I'm now using this code to import csv data into my database.(Thanks to Francis Avila)

```
 if (($handle = fopen($source_file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
     $columns = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",");
     $esc_columns = array();
     foreach ($columns as &$column) {
         $column1 = str_replace(".","",$column);
         $column = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/",",",$column1);
         $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName($column);
     }

     $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('custgroup');
     $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('user_id');
     $esc_columns[] = escapeSqlName('mylabel');

     $x = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", implode(',',$esc_columns));
     $xx = str_replace(' ', '', $x);

     $sqlsmttempl = 'INSERT DELAYED INTO %s (%s) VALUES (%s)';
     $sqlsmt = sprintf($sqlsmttempl,
         escapeSqlName($target_table), 
         $xx, 
         implode(',',array_fill(0, count($esc_columns), '?')) 
);


     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Data;","root",""); 

     $insert = $db->prepare($sqlsmt); 

     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, $max_line_length, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    while(count($data) < count($columns)) {
        $data[] = NULL;
    }

    $data[] = $_POST['custgroup'];
    $data[] = $_POST['user_id'];
    $data[] = $_POST['mylabel'];

    $insert->execute($data); 
}
```

I faced some problem in header blank space before , so I added

```
     $x = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", implode(',',$esc_columns));
     $xx = str_replace(' ', '', $x);
```

so now blank space will be ignored.

But how about blank space in data?(just in front and end of comma) . I tried `trim($data)` , but I know it is wrong.

And I have no clue how to handle the upload when the header contain other extra commas , such as :

`Name,Address,Phone,,,,,`(wrong) instead of just `Name,Address,Phone`(correct)

Any advice?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using rtrim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] ):

```
$x = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", implode(',',$esc_columns));
$xx = str_replace(' ', '', $x);
$xx = rtrim($xx,',');
```

For triming text in php you can use : ltrim (left trim), trim (trim on both sides), rtrim (right trim). All accept parameters ( string $str [, string $charlist ] ) $str - input string $charlist - string to be trimed

```
$xx = trim($xx); //exclude spaces both sides so for "  text  " => "text"
$xx = ltrim($xx); //exclude spaces left side so for "  text  " => "text  "
$xx = rtrim($xx); //exclude spaces right side so for "  text  " => "  text"

$xx = rtrim($xx,','); //adding second parameter ',' will not trim spaces, will trim coma
```

You cand add many commands as you want:

```
$x = preg_replace("/\s*,\s*/", ",", implode(',',$esc_columns));
$xx = str_replace(' ', '', $x);

$xx = trim($xx); //trim spaces from both sides
$xx = trim($xx,','); //trim comas from both sides
```

Note:

```
$xx = trim($xx,','); //this is faster (only one function call)

//equivalent with
$xx = ltrim($xx,',');
$xx = rtrim($xx,',');
```

Comment: Thanks to this great answer . I'm sorry..but can I ask one more question? How can I trim and rtrim my csv data as well?

Comment: Thanks again . But $xx is my header , the part I need to trim is the following data.